# $1-|z|^2 \le \sin^2(\lambda+\arg(z)) + 1 - \left[\frac{|z|e^\lambda}{1+|z|(e^\lambda-1)}\right]^2$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove that $\int_0^t {\sin^2(\lambda+\arg(z)) + 1 - \left[\frac{|z|e^\lambda}{1+|z|(e^\lambda-1)}\right]^2} d\lambda$ is strictly increasing and surjective. The author says to show that $1-|z|^2 \le \sin^2(\lambda+\arg(z)) + 1 - \left[\frac{|z|e^\lambda}{1+|z|(e^\lambda-1)}\right]^2$ is true and use the comparison test for improper integrals, but I can't prove it.

**Edit:** $z \in int(\mathbb{D})$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk on complex plain.